# Need to define UPS Declared value in magento for Orders cost $100 or more ? My shipping cost is coming different

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, ups

Need to define UPS Declared value in magento for Orders cost $100? My shipping cost is coming different for order values $100 or more. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience Magento's core functionality does not pass a declared value for the UPS shipping method.  To check you can turn on debug for the UPS shipping method in the system configurations.  With debug enabled all API requests and responses with UPS are stored in a log in Magento's var/log directory.  I'm guessing you'll see something like the following being passed to UPS for the package:

```
<Package>
  <PackagingType><Code>00</Code></PackagingType>
  <PackageWeight>
     <UnitOfMeasurement><Code>LBS</Code></UnitOfMeasurement>
    <Weight>1</Weight>
  </PackageWeight>
</Package><RateInformation><NegotiatedRatesIndicator/></RateInformation>
```

No declared value for the package.  To resolve I believe you need a custom or third party extension to pass declared value to UPS.  I think other carriers (like USPS) have this feature built-in to Magento.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your valuable feedback..Do you know any 3rd party exensions which can be used?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know of a commercial 3rd party extension for the requested functionality.  I ended up writing a custom solution to meet my requirements.  If familiar with creating Magento extensions it's pretty easy to extend Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups.php  _getXmlQuotes and add UPS's  <PackageServiceOptions> XML to pass shipment value.